# Ruby on Rails - User.tasks when User can be Task.creator or Task.owner

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class User
  has_many :created_tasks, class_name: 'Task', inverse_of: :creator, foreign_key: 'creator_id'
  has_many :owned_tasks, class_name: 'Task', inverse_of: :owner, foreign_key: 'owner_id'
  ...
end
```

and:

```
class Task
  belongs_to :creator,  class_name: 'User', inverse_of: :created_tasks
  belongs_to :owner,    class_name: 'User', inverse_of: :owned_tasks
  ...
end
```

I want to be able to call `@user.tasks` and get both `@user.created_tasks` and `@user.owned_tasks`

Is there an ActiveRecord way to do this or do I need to make a method?

I kinda want an ActiveRecord object back, but the method I can think of would look something like this:

```
class User
  ...
  def tasks
    ary = []
    ary << created_tasks
    ary << owned_tasks
    ary
  end
end
```

Is there an ActiveRecord (or just a better method) way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use an instance method like this

```
def tasks
  created_tasks.or(owned_tasks)
end
```

Comment: and it even returns an ActiveRecord object! Nice!